# Why React JS function not executing synchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually, I running a function on the onDrop event. Problem is that function is not executing synchronously, Even I am not doing the Async operation inside the loop.
console.log('inside on drop after for loop') executing before for loop, why?[Here, is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV1wu.png)

```
function traverseFileTree(item, path) {
        path = path || "";
        if (item.isFile) {
          // Get file
          item.file(function(file) {
            // console.log("File:", path + file.name);
                console.log('inside for loop')
                setFiles(pre => [...pre, file])
                setFilesSize(pre => pre + file.size)
            
          })
        } else if (item.isDirectory) {
          // Get folder contents
          let dirReader = item.createReader();
          dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            for (let i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
              traverseFileTree(entries[i], path + item.name + "/");
            }
          })
        }
    }

    function handelOnDrop(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        setFiles([])
        setFilesSize(0)

        let items = e.dataTransfer.items
        for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            // webkitGetAsEntry is where the magic happens
            let item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            if(files.length > 20) break
            if (item) {
                traverseFileTree(item)
            }else{
                setValidInput(false)
                break
            }
        }

        console.log('inside on drop after for loop')
       //other statements.
    }

<div onDrop={handelOnDrop}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `for-loop` alone is synchronous but the content inside may not, in your case, I think this block causes the function to run asynchronously:

```
dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
  for (let i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    traverseFileTree(entries[i], path + item.name + "/");
  }
})
```